# AppStoreConnectで「Apple Developer Programの使用許諾契約書が更新されました」と表示される

Tags: app-store

AppStoreConnectにアクセスすると、「Apple Developer Programの使用許諾契約書が更新されました」と表示されてしまいます。

青字で「アカウント」にサインインしと書かれているので、「アカウント」の文字をクリックして以下の記事と同じような手順を踏みました。
http://www.aqlier.com/2017/09/20/itunes-connect-message/

しかし、「Apple Developer Programの使用許諾契約書が更新されました」の表示は消えません。
新規アプリのApp内課金を追加しようとしても「契約の更新」という以下のような表示が出て、App内課金を追加できません。

> 契約の更新
> Review the updated Paid Applications Schedule.
> In order to update your existing apps, create new in-app purchases, and submit new apps to the App Store, the user with the Legal role (Account Holder) must review and accept the Paid Applications Schedule (Schedule 2 to the Apple Developer Program License Agreement) in the Agreements, Tax, and Bankingmodule.
>
> To accept this agreement, they must have already accepted the latest version of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement in their account on the developer website.

この契約の更新というのは何なのでしょうか？
どうしたらこの表示を消すことが出来ますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 表記の通りですが、Apple Developer Programの使用許諾契約書https://developer.apple.com/terms/ が更新されたので、ACCOUNT HOLDER（あなたが所属しているApple Developer Programの管理者）に連絡して、同意して貰う必要があります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

表記の通りですが、[Apple Developer Programの使用許諾契約書](https://developer.apple.com/terms/) が更新されたので、ACCOUNT HOLDER（あなたが所属しているApple Developer Programの管理者）に連絡して、同意して貰う必要があります。

ACCOUNT HOLDERが誰なのか？はこちらのURLにアクセスできれば確認できるはずです。
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。自分自身がACCOUNT HOLDERなのですが、その場合どこで何を同意したら良いですか？

Comment: なるほど、 https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/ の上の方に同意するためのボタン（Review Summary のような表記）がないでしょうか？

Comment: 最初、そちらに同意するようなボタン等が出ていて、すべてに同意したりContinueしていったりして手順を終えたのですが、不思議なことに状況が変わっていないのです。今は「同意する」などのボタンは表示されておりませんが、相変わらず https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ には「Apple Developer Programの使用許諾契約が更新されました」の表示は出続けています。

Comment: なるほど、まだ何か同意する項目が足りていないのかもしれませんね。 https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/#/ のページにはなにか警告⚠マークが出ていないでしょうか？

Comment: そちらの有料Appの項目に警告が入っていて、同意すると、「Apple Developer Programの使用許諾契約が更新されました」の表示が消え、問題が解決しました！App内課金の実装もできるようになりました。親切に教えて頂きありがとうございます！！